# Javascript hour countdown error

Tags: php, javascript

I have a countdown timer which transfers time from H:i:s to long version using this script:

```
function parseTime() {
var timeLeftStr;
var timeLeft = 0;

timeLeftStr = document.getElementById("timeleft").innerHTML;

timeLeftStr.replace(/(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)/, function () {
    for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length - 2; i++) {
        // Convert to ms
        timeLeft += arguments[i] * Math.pow(60, 3 - i) * 1000;
    }
});

countdown(new Date(timeLeft));
}

function countdown(timeLeft) {
var hours = timeLeft.getHours();
var minutes = timeLeft.getMinutes();
var seconds = timeLeft.getSeconds();

if (timeLeft.valueOf() == 0) {
    document.getElementById("timeleft").innerHTML = "0 seconds";
window.location = 'home.php?pageid=' + getURLParam("pageid");
    return false;
} else {
    document.getElementById("timeleft").innerHTML =
        (hours == 0 ? "" : hours + (hours == 1 ? " hour" : " hours")) +
        (minutes == 0 ? "" : (hours ? (seconds ? ", " : " and ") : " ") + minutes + (minutes == 1 ? " minute" : " minutes")) +
        (seconds == 0 ? "" : (hours || minutes ? " and " : "") + seconds + (seconds == 1 ? " second" : " seconds"));

    setTimeout(function () { countdown(new Date(timeLeft - 1000)); }, 1000);
}
}

window.onload = parseTime;
```

The error is that a user of mine who lives in Australia keeps getting the wrong "hour"
The original timer would say something like "23:45:05" but when the countdown timer starts it says "10 hours, 45 minutes and 5 seconds" rather than 23 hours.

Any idea why this could be happening? Thank you.

Im not that great at JS, this was created by a friend.

Worked it out in the end.

Answer (score 0):

well, this happens because javascript gets the current date and time from the client: so when it's 23 o'clock in your country, in another part of the world a client who make a request to the page will show a different hour (and probably day)

if you want to show the same time everywhere you should get the `server` date and time so you're sure it's the same for every client or you should get the [local timezone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) and apply an offset.

You could take a look a this similar discussion: [Javascript countdown using absolute timezone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8805613/javascript-countdown-using-absolute-timezone)

Comment: How can I make it take the server time?

Comment: How exactly would I get the script to get the server time rather than the local time?

Comment: make an ajax call to a server-side resource sending back hour, minutes and seconds. if it sounds too complicated for your capabilities just use `getTimezoneOffset()` in javascript. Please have also a look to this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8805613/javascript-countdown-using-absolute-timezone

Comment: JavaScript is actually complicated for me too. I write PHP only. I will try to have a go though, thanks.

Comment: How can I implement it into my current script? I actually don't have a clue how to fix it, I will end up making it worse.