# convert local timezone to GMT in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to convert a date object in HST format to a standard format. But the date object returns NaN.

```
completeByTimestamp="1/25/2013 5:15 PM HST";
var completByTmUTC= (new Date(completeByTimestamp)).toUTCString();
```

Comment: Similar to: [Javascript countdown using absolute timezone?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8805613/402706)

Comment: you can use timezone.js plugin refering this [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript

Comment: It will change during Day light saving if I try to use offset value.

Comment: @NickJ Sorry for the Java tag