# Convert IST (Indian Standard Time) time to any other standard time in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework

I am a novice in JavaScript.

My need is to change IST (Indian Standard Time) time to any other standard. For Example PST (Pakistan Standard Time). User enters IST time 10:30(HH:MM) in a text field. How can I convert this time to PST.

Comment: See [this answer on a previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8805724/2817961)

Comment: @Justin K ... Thanx for quick reply but how change user input time like 10:30(HH:MM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how change user input time like 10:30(HH:MM)

You can use a split on the input value:

```
var parts = inputElement.value.split(':'),
    hours = parseInt(parts[0], 10),
    mins  = parseInt(parts[1], 10);
```

(error checking should of course be applied as well).

Then use this answer as Justin K references:
[Javascript countdown using absolute timezone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8805613/javascript-countdown-using-absolute-timezone/8805724#8805724)