# Create a daily text-based countdown to a specific cut-off time from scratch in js or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown, countdowntimer

I am working on a project for a client and I was hoping I could get some help with how to do this since I am relatively new to Javascript (while I have alot more familiarity with CSS/HTML at this time).

**Request Details**
Install a countdown timer that countdown to 5pm EST, Monday-Friday. The timer should be textual (or at least able to be styled via CSS).

This is for an online store on a closed source platform with no access to server side programming (HTML/CSS/Javascript only). Server type is IIS 6.X

**Requirements**
Timer must automatically restart at 5pm (Monday-Friday)
Timer must continue to function even if a postback/Ajax Refresh occurs on page*

*The product detail pages where this will be showing have Ajax panels that refresh the page based on certain actions. The countdown should continue to function even after a dynamic or full page refresh.

**What I have done so far**
I have attempted to utilize various plugins for use in this project, but I have yet to find one that is designed to restart daily.

I am lost on the best way to proceed here and while I know what I need can be done in Javascript (or jQuery) I guess I lack the experience to be able to determine what that is.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This might help you get started http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8805613/javascript-countdown-using-absolute-timezone and maybe this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191865/code-for-a-simple-javascript-countdown-timer

Comment: Please post a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with any one of your attempts, and we could very quickly modify it for you to (1) detect 5pm EST and (2) restart the timer. Asking the question without a code sample, though, is like asking us to write it for you from scratch.

Comment: you are going to have to provide a starting point in code, and show where your problems are, won't get anyone to write this for you

Comment: I dont want the whole thing written for me, I was mainly looking for some direction. I'll review the links and comments and post an update.